# Warning: Failed to find package 'system-images;android-30;google_apis_playstore;x86 platforms

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-sdk-manager

Im getting the following output when try to install android SDK using sdkmanager cmd-line

```
 ---------------------------------------
Accept? (y/N): All SDK package licenses accepted

yes: standard output: Broken pipe
Loading package information...                                                  
Loading local repository...                                                     
Info: Parsing legacy package: /opt/android/cmdline-tools
Info: Parsing /opt/android/tools/package.xml
[                                       ] 3% Loading local repository...        
[                                       ] 3% Fetch remote repository...         
[=                                      ] 3% Fetch remote repository...         
[=                                      ] 4% Fetch remote repository...         
[=                                      ] 5% Fetch remote repository...         
[==                                     ] 5% Fetch remote repository...         
[==                                     ] 6% Fetch remote repository...         
[==                                     ] 7% Fetch remote repository...         
[==                                     ] 7% Computing updates...               
[===                                    ] 8% Computing updates...               
Warning: Failed to find package 'system-images;android-30;google_apis_playstore;x86 platforms;android-30 build-tools;31.0.0-rc5 platform-tools emulator'
[===                                    ] 10% Computing updates...              
                                                                                
yes: standard output: Broken pipe
[===                                    ] 10% Computing updates...              
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

[image: screenshot]

Any idea what could be missed?

here is the command that I have used

```
  mkdir -p /home/runner/.android && touch /home/runner/.android/repositories.cfg
  cd $ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/bin && yes | ./sdkmanager --sdk_root=$ANDROID_HOME --licenses
  cd $ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/bin && yes | ./sdkmanager --sdk_root=$ANDROID_HOME --verbose --no_https "system-images;android-30;google_apis_playstore;x86 platforms;android-30 build-tools;31.0.0-rc5 platform-tools emulator"
```

Answer (score 4):

use the sdkmanger to identify the properly package name:

`sdkmanager --list`

[image: sdkmanager]

Another thing split in more then one command:

```bash
mkdir -p /home/runner/.android && touch /home/runner/.android/repositories.cfg
pushd $ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/bin
yes | ./sdkmanager --sdk_root=$ANDROID_HOME --licenses
./sdkmanager --sdk_root=$ANDROID_HOME --verbose --channel=0 "system-images;android-30;google_apis_playstore;x86"
./sdkmanager --sdk_root=$ANDROID_HOME --verbose --channel=0 "build-tools;31.0.0"
./sdkmanager --sdk_root=$ANDROID_HOME --verbose --channel=0 "platform-tools"
./sdkmanager --sdk_root=$ANDROID_HOME --verbose --channel=0 "emulator"
popd
```

Answer (score 2):

In the ' comma change it to " like "platforms;android-29"
i solved my like that

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: saved it !!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**
Use this command.
sdkmanager "system-images;android-31;default;x86_64"

Proved:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGRl6.png)

**Root Cause of this issue:**
Some machine support 64 bit operation thats why that command
(sdkmanager "system-images;android-31;default;x86") does not work in that machine.

Comment: Wrap the command in the <code> characters ```